# Count while loop, in specific loop time do something else and continue while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, logic

This code print like this. **16 times pictures** then **16 times same codes** again 16 times pictures then 16 times different codes.

I want that the loop of code **load in every loop new code from the database**. Not the same code.

Thanks in advance, I could not find any logic for that.

Now it is working.
The trick was to insert all the codes to an array. $codes[] = $row['koodi'];

Then print array.

```
$resturantID = 11; // resturant ID 

$counter = 0; // count amount of loop 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lappu WHERE resturantID = $resturantID");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $code = $row['code'];
    $counter++;

}

for ($x = 1; $x <= $counter; $x++) {

if (in_array($x, array(17,34,51,68,85,102,119,136,153,170,187,204,221,238,255,272,289,306,323))) {
                    for ($b = 1; $b <= 16; $b++) {
                        echo 'pictures'.'<br>';
                    }

                    for ($b = 1; $b <= 16; $b++) {
                        echo $code.'<br>';
                    }
                }

}
```

Comment: the above code seems incorrect - there are different amount of opening versus closing braces `{` and `}`

Comment: @RamRaider thanks, I removed the extra brace but that’s not the point.

Comment: How is the `$code` variable to change? Another query to the database? If so on what criteria? It is not clear. Also what numbers are they in the array - are they acceptable IDs from the `lappu` table??

Comment: @RamRaider Yes. How to get in every for loop new $code variable not while loop? I used inside for loop new query but it printed all codes. Numbers are primary key of table like 1,2,3,4 etc. yes they are acceptable IDs from lappu table.

Comment: I have an idea but not sure ....I'll post it and you can take a look anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$resId = 11;


$counter = 0;
$ids=array(17,34,51,68,85,102,119,136,153,170,187,204,221,238,255,272,289,306,323);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare( 'select * from `lappu` where `resturantid` = :id' );
$stmt->bindParam( ':id', $resId );
$stmt->execute();

$codes=array();

while( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
    $codes[ $row['resturantid'] ] = $row['code'];
    $counter++;
}








for( $x = 1; $x <= $counter; $x++ ) {
    if ( in_array( $x, $ids ) ) {

        $code=$codes[ $x ];

        for ( $b = 1; $b <= 16; $b++ ) {
            echo 'pictures'.'<br>';
        }

        for ( $b = 1; $b <= 16; $b++ ) {
            echo $code.'<br>';
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I get 'notice' from this line of code. I think now It is empty.  Notice: Undefined offset: 17   code line:   $code=$codes[$x];

Comment: it was a guess...without knowing the contents of the table it's hard to know for sure. Like I say - it was just an idea as I don't know how many `code` will be returned from the database query

Comment: I liked your logic. $row['resturantid'] is just to get the right codes. codes are around 300 that is why I wroted in array those numbers.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: no problem - glad I was able to point you in the right direction